# eroor while deleting entry and send resultset from servlet to jsp page

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.xml.ws.Response;

import com.sun.corba.se.spi.activation.Repository;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class DeleteControl
 */
public class DeleteControl extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    ResultSet rs = null;
    Statement st = null;
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public DeleteControl() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String str = request.getParameter("hiddenValue");
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Student","root","root");
            //here sonoo is the database name, root is the username and root is the password

            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("delete from login where studentId= ? ;");
            ps.setString(1, str);
            ps.executeUpdate();
            st = con.createStatement();
            rs= st.executeQuery("select * from login");
            con.close();
            }catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e);}
            request.setAttribute("resultset", rs);
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("userHome.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

and it gives error like this

> ```
> HTTP Status 500 -
>
> type Exception report
>
> message
>
> description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:502)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:412)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>   DeleteControl.doGet(DeleteControl.java:57)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
> root cause
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:865)
> ```
>
> org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:794)
>     org.apache.jsp.userHome_jsp._jspService(userHome_jsp.java:106)
>     org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>     DeleteControl.doGet(DeleteControl.java:57)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717) root
>   cause
>
> java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
>     com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1078)
>     com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
>     com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:975)
>     com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:920)
>     com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkClosed(ResultSetImpl.java:804)
>     com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.next(ResultSetImpl.java:6986)
>     org.apache.jsp.userHome_jsp._jspService(userHome_jsp.java:81)
>     org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>     DeleteControl.doGet(DeleteControl.java:57)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717) note The
>   full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache
>   Tomcat/6.0.35 logs.
>
> Apache Tomcat/6.0.35

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a terrible mess and you create several memory leaks here. Use a `DataSource` factory like Tomcat JDBC Pool and Apache Commmons DbUtils to focus on your problem.

Moreover, you do not perform a `conn.commit()` after the delete.  You are in autocommit mode. You should never work in autocommit mode.

Your pass a result set which has already been closed by the connection.

Comment: thanks for answer i have one more question if i m going to close coonection after the forwrd method then how can code after the forwad method execute ??

Comment: You can use a finally block but the best is to detach the data before the view is rendered.